# Pa11y actions reference / documentation

Tags: pa11y

How do you enter values to match a name="" attribute, or class=""? I'm guessing that # is referring to id="" only? If HTML ID attributes are not available there needs to be a way to match other attributes or the element itself.

Is there a reference for how to use actions?

```
actions: [
    'set field #login_field to abc',
    'set field #password to defghi',
    'click element #password"',
    'wait for url to be http://github.com'
],
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the actions reference, although the documentation is very limited for this project. Selectors seem limited to IDs as far as I can tell, not much good if there aren't any. I was hoping for Selenium-type selectors inc Xpath.

[Pa11y Documentation - Actions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pa11y#actions)

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation that you linked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pa11y#user-content-click-element) (emphasis mine):

> This allows you to click an element by passing in **a CSS selector**. This action takes the form click element .
> [...]
> You can use any valid [query selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), including classes and types.

You should be able to use any valid CSS selector, including IDs, classes, and more complex CSS selectors. For example, to click on an element with `class="myClass"` you could use:

```json
{
    "actions": [
        "click element .myClass",
        "wait for path to be /foo"
    ]
}
```

Running pa11y using the `--debug` flag should help you understand if the actions are working correctly. For an example like the one above you should be able to see an output similar to this:

```
Welcome to Pa11y

 > Running Pa11y on URL https://www.example.com/
[...]
 > Running actions
 > Debug: Running action: click element .myClass
 > Debug:   ✔︎ Action complete: click-element
 > Debug: Running action: wait for path to be /foo
 > Debug:   ✔︎ Action complete: wait-for-url
 > Finished running actions
[...]
 > Debug: Document title: "Foo"

No issues found!
```